# Why doesn't python list remove() work for list of plots?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to do some animation with FuncAnimation. Instead of using .set_data() I'm using this alternative structure:

```
def update_plot(frame, y, plot):
    plot[0].remove()
    plot[0] = ax.scatter(np.sin(y[frame,0]),-np.cos(y[frame,0]), color = "orange")

#(...)

# Initial
plot = [ax.scatter(np.sin(y[0,0]),-np.cos(y[0,0]), color = "orange")]

# Animate
animate = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_plot, nmax, fargs = (y, plot))
animate.save('pendulum.gif',writer='imagemagick')
```

This works well. However, if I use ax.plot() instead of ax.scatter():

```
def update_plot(frame, y, plot):
    plot[0].remove()
    plot[0] = ax.plot(np.sin(y[frame,0]),-np.cos(y[frame,0]),'o', color = "orange")

# Initial
plot = [ax.plot(np.sin(y[0,0]),-np.cos(y[0,0]),'o', color = "orange")]

# Animate
animate = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_plot, nmax, fargs = (y, plot))
animate.save('pendulum.gif',writer='imagemagick')
```

the code fails because of the plot[0].remove() with the following error:

```
remove() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

Why is that the case?

Comment: You didn't tell `remove()` what to remove?

Comment: @Barmar I didn't, it seems to work for ax.scatter() and ax.quiver(), but not for ax.plot().

Comment: Because `ax.scatter` returns a `PathCollection` (which derives from Actor, which provides `remove(self)`, whereas `ax.plot` returns a Python list of `Line2D` objects (and Python list has `remove` with a different meaning an signature). Also be aware that you're calling `remove` on the first element of `plot`, not `plot` itself.

Comment: Are you looking for ax.axis(“off”)? The axes are in a list but removing them from the list doesn’t remove them from the plot.

Comment: I'd assume you just need to iterate over the inner list and invoke `remove` on each of the `Line2D` objects in it. Assuming you're looking at calling the MatPlotLib `remove` function.

Comment: ^ that's what `.clear()` is for

Comment: I believe you are confusing the list of one element `plot` and its contents, which may also be a list. It actually sounds like you are after `https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.autoscale.html`

Comment: clear just empties the list, it doesn't alter the contents.I don't know why the axes would be in the list anyway, `ax.plot` does not return it.

Comment: @mdurant I was missunderstanding. Anyway calling `plot[0].clear()` doesn't seem to work... the code doesn't crash but my frames still overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so here is the line you need:

```
ax.lines.clear()
```

This is because `ax` retains its own list of things it is plotting, and anything you do to your own lists won't affect that. So, this line removes all the lines, and then you can start adding new ones.

Answer (score 1):

ax.[scatter](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html) returns [PathCollection](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection) object, it inherits function [remove(self)](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.AsteriskPolygonCollection.remove) from parent [Collection](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.Collection).
However, ax.[plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html) returns a list of [Line2D](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D) objects.
In the case of plot, you are calling remove from a list type, but [list.remove](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) needs 1 argument.

In the case of scatter, you're are calling remove from PathCollection type, that doesn't need arguments.

You can check the type before calling remove, using isinstance to check if plot is type list or PathCollection.

```py
def update_plot(frame, y, plot):
    if isinstance(plot[0], list):
        plot[0][0].remove()
        plot[0][0] = ax.plot(np.sin(y[frame,0]),-np.cos(y[frame,0]),'o', color = "orange")
    else:
        plot[0].remove()
        plot[0] = ax.scatter(np.sin(y[frame,0]),-np.cos(y[frame,0]), color = "orange")
```

Comment: I know how to use .remove() with a numerical list but I'm confused by the use in this case. If I use plot[0].remove(ax.plot(...)) I get that there's no such as element in the list. Note that for ax.scatter() and ax.quiver() it works nice without any argument.

Comment: I have updated my answer, could you add the asked information?

Comment: You're better off just doing `plot[0] = ax.plot(...)[0]` or `plot[0], *_ = ax.plot(...)` or `plot[0], = ax.plot(...)` in `update_plot`

Comment: Do you mind editing my answer? I understood what you mean, but I don't know how to write it.